# DragDrop on QTableView not working

Tags: c++, qt5

I hame the following class that basically contains an `std::vector<PassoProgramma>`, and constitutes the model for a QTableView.

~  *Programma.h*  ~

```
#ifndef PROGRAMMA_H
#define PROGRAMMA_H
#include <vector>
#include "PassoProgramma.h"
#include <QString>
#include <string>
#include <QAbstractTableModel>
#include <QFont>


class Programma  : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Programma(QString, std::vector<PassoProgramma>,  std::map<unsigned char, Asse>* const);
    Programma(const std::string, std::map<unsigned char, Asse>* const);

    void salva(const std::string, const std::string = "");
    int sizeHintForRow() const ;
    bool isIndexValid(const QModelIndex& index) const;
    inline std::string getNome() const  { return nome; };
    inline std::vector<PassoProgramma>* const getPassi() { return &Passi; }
    inline bool isSalvato() const { return salvato; }

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex&) const override;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex&) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex&, int) const override;
    QVariant headerData(int, Qt::Orientation, int) const override;
    bool dropMimeData(const QMimeData*, Qt::DropAction , int , int , const QModelIndex&) override;
    bool removeRows(int, int, const QModelIndex&) override;
    bool insertRows(int, int, const QModelIndex&) override;
    bool moveRows(const QModelIndex&, const int, const int, const QModelIndex&, int) override;
    QMimeData* mimeData(const QModelIndexList&) const override;
    Qt::DropActions supportedDropActions() const override;
    Qt::ItemFlags flags(const QModelIndex&) const override;
    bool setData(const QModelIndex&, const QVariant&, int) override;
    QStringList mimeTypes() const override;

    PassoProgramma* operator[](int i)
    {
        if(i < Passi.size())    return &Passi.at(i);
        else throw new std::exception();
    };
    static const QFont headerFont;
    static const QFont dataFont;

private:
    struct myLocale : std::numpunct<char>
    {
    protected :
        char do_thousands_sep() const override { return '\0' ; }
        char do_decimal_point() const override { return '.' ; }
        std::string do_grouping() const override { return "" ; }
    };

    std::vector<PassoProgramma> Passi;
    std::string nome;
    bool salvato;
    std::map<unsigned char, Asse>* const assi;

};


class ELoadException : public std::exception
{
private:
    std::string message_;
public:
    ELoadException(const std::string& message) : message_(message) {};
    virtual const char* what() const throw()
    {
        return message_.c_str();
    }
};

#endif
```

~ *Programma.cpp* ~

```
#include "Programma.h"
#include "Editor.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <regex>
#include <QSize>
#include <QMimeData>
#include <QDataStream>

const QFont Programma::headerFont("Open Sans", 17, QFont::Weight::DemiBold);
const QFont Programma::dataFont("Open Sans", 22, QFont::Weight::DemiBold);


inline std::string& ltrim(std::string& str, const std::string& chars = "\t\v\f ")
{
    str.erase(0, str.find_first_not_of(chars));
    return str;
}

inline std::string& rtrim(std::string& str, const std::string& chars = "\t\v\f ")
{
    str.erase(str.find_last_not_of(chars) + 1);
    return str;
}

inline std::string& trim(std::string& str, const std::string& chars = "\t\v\f ")
{
    return ltrim(rtrim(str, chars), chars);
}


Programma::Programma(QString nome, std::vector<PassoProgramma> passi, std::map<unsigned char, Asse>* const assi) : Passi(passi), assi(assi)
{
    this->nome = nome.toStdString();

}


Programma::Programma(std::string fileFullName, std::map<unsigned char, Asse>* const assi) : assi(assi)
{
    std::ifstream stream;
    try
    {
        stream.open(fileFullName, std::ios::in);
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        std::stringstream st;
        st << "Error opening file \"" << fileFullName << "\".\nError:   " << e.what();
        throw ELoadException(st.str());
    }

    int slash = fileFullName.find_last_of("/");
    nome = fileFullName.substr(slash + 1);
    Passi.reserve(100);

    std::string line;
    char* token;
    unsigned int lineCount = 0, tokenCount;

    while(std::getline(stream, line))  //  Per ogni linea del file estraggo fino a 6 token
    {
        if(trim(line).length() == 0) continue;

        //  Controllo che la linea appena letta dal file contenga esattamente 2, 4 o 6 coppie <lettera, float>.
        if(!std::regex_match(line, std::regex(R"(^(?:[A-Z] [-+]?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?(?: |$)){1,3}$)")))
        {
            std::stringstream st;
            st << "Line #" << lineCount << " of file \"" << fileFullName << "\" is invalid.";
            throw ELoadException(st.str());
        }

        ++lineCount;
        PassoProgramma passo;
        tokenCount = 0;
        char* cstr = new char[line.length() + 1];
        std::strcpy(cstr, line.c_str());  //  Converto la stringa costante in char* non costante, per poterla fornire a strtok.
        token = strtok(cstr, " ");
        while(token)
        {
            ++tokenCount;
            switch(tokenCount)
            {
                case 1:
                    passo.asse1 = &assi->at(token[0]);
                    break;
                case 2:
                {
                    std::istringstream iStr(token);
                    iStr >> passo.target1;
                    break;
                }
                case 3:
                    passo.asse2 = &assi->at(token[0]);
                    break;
                case 4:
                {
                    std::istringstream iStr(token);
                    iStr >> passo.target2;
                    break;
                }
                case 5:
                    passo.asse3 = &assi->at(token[0]);
                    break;
                case 6:
                {
                    std::istringstream iStr(token);
                    iStr >> passo.target3;
                    break;
                }
            }
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");  //  Vado al prossimo token senza cambiare la stringa da dividere
        }
        Passi.push_back(passo);
    }
    salvato = true;
}


void Programma::salva(const std::string path, const std::string nome /* facoltativo; se specificato costituir?? il nome del file */)
{
    if(nome != "")
        this->nome = nome;
    std::stringstream destFileFullName("");
    destFileFullName << path << "/" << this->nome << ".prg";

    std::ofstream f;
    f.imbue(std::locale(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8"), new Programma::myLocale()));
    try
    {
        f.open(destFileFullName.str());
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        std::stringstream st;
        st << "Error writing to file \"" << st.str() << "\".\nError:   " << e.what();
        throw ELoadException(st.str());
    }

    for(const PassoProgramma& passo : Passi)
    {
        f << passo.toString() << std::endl;
    }
    //  f.flush();
    f.close();
    salvato = true;
}


int Programma::rowCount(const QModelIndex& parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return Passi.size();
}

int Programma::columnCount(const QModelIndex& parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return 6;
}

QVariant Programma::data(const QModelIndex& index, int role) const
{
    if(!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    if(role == Qt::TextAlignmentRole)
    {
        return QVariant(Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter);
    }
    else if(role == Qt::DisplayRole || role == Qt::EditRole)
    {
        switch(index.column())
        {
            case 0:
                return QString(Passi.at(index.row()).asse1->asse);
                break;
            case 1:
                return QString::number(Passi.at(index.row()).target1, 'f', Passi.at(index.row()).asse1->getCifreDecimali()).replace("-", Editor::MENO);
                break;
            case 2:
                return (Passi.at(index.row()).getNumeroAssi() < 2) ? QVariant() : QString(Passi.at(index.row()).asse2->asse);
                break;
            case 3:
                return (Passi.at(index.row()).getNumeroAssi() < 2) ? QVariant() : QString::number(Passi.at(index.row()).target2, 'f', Passi.at(index.row()).asse2->getCifreDecimali()).replace("-", Editor::MENO);
                break;
            case 4:
                return (Passi.at(index.row()).getNumeroAssi() < 3) ? QVariant() : QString(Passi.at(index.row()).asse3->asse);
                break;
            case 5:
                return (Passi.at(index.row()).getNumeroAssi() < 3) ? QVariant() : QString::number(Passi.at(index.row()).target3, 'f', Passi.at(index.row()).asse3->getCifreDecimali()).replace("-", Editor::MENO);
                break;
        }
    }
    else if(role == Qt::SizeHintRole)
    {
        switch(index.column())
        {
            case 0:
            case 2:
            case 4:
                return QSize(50, 42);
            case 1:
            case 3:
            case 5:
                return QSize(105, 42);
        }
    }
    else if(role == Qt::FontRole) return dataFont;
    return QVariant();
}

QVariant Programma::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const
{
    if(Qt::Orientation::Horizontal == orientation)
    {
        if(role == Qt::DisplayRole)
        {
            switch(section)
            {
                case 0:
                case 2:
                case 4:
                    return QString("ASSE");
                case 1:
                case 3:
                case 5:
                    return QString("TARGET");
            }
        }
        else if(role == Qt::TextAlignmentRole)
        {
            return Qt::AlignCenter;
        }
        else if(role == Qt::FontRole) return headerFont;
        else if(role == Qt::SizeHintRole)
        {
            switch(section)
            {
                case 0:
                case 2:
                case 4: return QSize(50, 28);
                case 1:
                case 3:
                case 5: return QSize(105, 28);
            }
        }

    }
    else
    {
        if(role == Qt::DisplayRole)
        {
            return QString::number(section + 1);
        }
        else if(role == Qt::TextAlignmentRole)
        {
            return Qt::AlignRight;
        }
        /*
        else if(role == Qt::SizeHintRole)
        {
            return QSize(45, 45);
        }
        */
        else if(role == Qt::FontRole) return headerFont;
    }

    return QVariant();
}

int Programma::sizeHintForRow() const
{
    return 42;
}

bool Programma::dropMimeData(const QMimeData* data, Qt::DropAction action, int row, int column, const QModelIndex& parent)
{
    QByteArray encodedData = data->data("application/text");
    QDataStream stream(&encodedData, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QStringList newItems;
    int rows = 0;

    //  I dati contengono una stringa multilinea: devo dividerli nelle varie linee.
    while(!stream.atEnd())
    {
        QString text;
        stream >> text;
        newItems << text;
        ++rows;
    }

    //  Divido ogni linea nei token di cui è composta.
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        PassoProgramma nuovoPasso;
        int tokenCount = 0;
        std::string token(strtok(&(newItems[i].toStdString()[0]), " "));
        while(token.length() > 0)
        {
            ++tokenCount;
            switch(tokenCount)
            {
                case 1:
                    nuovoPasso.asse1 = &assi->at(token[0]);;
                    break;
                case 2:
                {
                    nuovoPasso.target1 = std::stof(token);
                    break;
                }
                case 3:
                    nuovoPasso.asse2 = &assi->at(token[0]);
                    break;
                case 4:
                {
                    nuovoPasso.target2 = std::stof(token);
                    break;
                }
                case 5:
                    nuovoPasso.asse3 = &assi->at(token[0]);
                    break;
                case 6:
                {
                    nuovoPasso.target3 = std::stof(token);
                    break;
                }
            }
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");  //  Va al prossimo token senza modificare la stringa da dividere
        }
        Passi.insert(Passi.begin() + row, nuovoPasso);
    }
    salvato = false;
    return true;
}

bool Programma::removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex())
{
    if(row < 0 || row >= Passi.size() || count <= 0 || (row + count) > Passi.size())
    {
        return false;
    }
    beginRemoveRows(parent, row, row + count - 1);
    Passi.erase(Passi.begin() + row, Passi.begin() + row + count);
    endRemoveRows();

    salvato = false;
    return true;
}


bool Programma::insertRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex& parent = QModelIndex())
{
    if(row < 0 || count < 0 || row + count >= Passi.size())
    {
        return false;
    }
    beginInsertRows(parent, row, row + count - 1);
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        Passi.insert(Passi.begin() + row, PassoProgramma());
    }
    endInsertRows();
    return true;
}

bool Programma::moveRows(const QModelIndex& sourceParent, const int sourceRow, const int count, const QModelIndex& destinationParent, int destinationChild)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        PassoProgramma toBeMoved = Passi.at(sourceRow + i);
        Passi.insert(Passi.begin() + destinationChild + i, toBeMoved);
        Passi.erase(Passi.begin() + sourceRow + i);
    }
    salvato = false;
    return true;
}

QMimeData* Programma::mimeData(const QModelIndexList& indexes) const
{
    QMimeData* mimeData = new QMimeData();
    QByteArray encodedData;

    QDataStream stream(&encodedData, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

    foreach(const QModelIndex& index, indexes)
    {
        if(index.isValid())
        {
            stream << Passi.at(index.row()).toString().c_str() << '\n';
        }
    }

    mimeData->setData("application/text", encodedData);
    return mimeData;
}

Qt::DropActions Programma::supportedDropActions() const
{
    return Qt::MoveAction;
}

Qt::ItemFlags Programma::flags(const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    if(index.isValid())
    {
        if(index.column() < 2 && Passi[index.row()].getNumeroAssi() == 0
                || index.column() < 4 && Passi[index.row()].getNumeroAssi() == 1
                || Passi[index.row()].getNumeroAssi() >= 2
        )
            return QAbstractItemModel::flags(index) | Qt::ItemIsEditable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled;
    }
    return QAbstractItemModel::flags(index) & ~Qt::ItemIsEnabled;
}

bool Programma::setData(const QModelIndex& index, const QVariant& value, int role)
{
    if(index.isValid() && role == Qt::EditRole)
    {
        switch(index.column())
        {
            case 0: Passi[index.row()].asse1 = &assi->at(value.toString()[0].toLatin1());
                break;
            case 1: Passi[index.row()].target1 = value.toString().replace(Editor::MENO, "-").toFloat();
                break;
            case 2: Passi[index.row()].asse2 = &assi->at(value.toString()[0].toLatin1());
                break;
            case 3: Passi[index.row()].target2 = value.toString().replace(Editor::MENO, "-").toFloat();
                break;
            case 4: Passi[index.row()].asse3 = &assi->at(value.toString()[0].toLatin1());
                break;
            case 5: Passi[index.row()].target3 = value.toString().replace(Editor::MENO, "-").toFloat();
                break;
        }
        salvato = false;
        emit dataChanged(index, index);
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}

bool Programma::isIndexValid(const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    return index.row() >= 0 && index.row() < Passi.size() && index.isValid();
}

QStringList Programma::mimeTypes() const
{
    return QStringList() << "application/text";
}
```

As you can see, I have overridden (and then implemented in Programma.cpp) all the basic events for moving, deleting and creating rows.
I have a button which deletes the current row and one that inserts a new row; furthermore, I wish to reorder the rows via drag&drop.
The aforementioned two buttons do work, but the drag&drop feature isn't working: the rows of the table do move, but none of the methods `moveRows`, `mimeData` and `dropMimeData` ever gets called. In consequence of this, the row header numbers follow the respective data; instead the headers should be renumebred automatically after each dragdrop.

Why does this happen?
I stitched to the examples provided in the Qt5 documentation.

Maybe my problem is trivial, but I'm developing in C++11 under Linux being a total newbie in both.  (Only my boss knows why).

Comment: You have posted the same question without improving it, do you think your code is a [mcve]?

Comment: The above code is for the model. For drag and drop to work your view (`QTableView`) should be dnd enabled. You should first go through the examples of drag and drop given by Qt. You'll then get some idea how to start doing a drag and drop. In `QTableView`, override `dragEnterEvent`, `dragMoveEvent`, `dropEvent`, to handle the `QMimeData` that is dropped. Without doing so how should your table know how to handle the dropped stuff?

Comment: @eyllanesc
I certainly can't publish my whole C++ project. Furthermore, I don't think other source files could help you helping me.

Comment: @Marcus
The tutorials in the Qt5 website say that it isn't necessary to subclass a QTableView, and that it is sufficient that the model overrides some methods – the way I did. The QTableView shouldm't _handle_ the stuff being dropped at all: it just should report to the model which indices are being dropped.
   
What am I missing?

Comment: @ErosRavera 
I never told him to share with me his whole project, not even his project. I've asked for a [mcve]. a minimum code that you could create that has the characteristic of being reproducible, effort and provide that [mcve], and we will also endeavor to try to help you.

Comment: @eyllanesc
Providing an "example project" simply means rewriting almost all classes of my project from scratch.
So, here is my full project:  [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zsbuf4mw84snfbg/D378.zip)
Now obviously can't  provide more stuff.   ;-)

Comment: @Ernesto_Che Yes, that's what it means. It is to invest a little time in creating that [mcve], remember that the question and answer should serve not only you but the community. And if you can not reproduce your problem then it will not serve anyone. :D

Comment: @Ernesto_Che In such a case, you should at the very least set `QTableView::setAcceptDrops(...)`

Comment: Also, te manual clearly says: `To be able to receive media dropped on a widget, call setAcceptDrops(true) for the widget, and reimplement the dragEnterEvent() and dropEvent() event handler functions.`

Comment: @Marcus
All the flags inherent to drag&drop are set via Qt Designer.  :-)   
And...
a dragEnter event would never be fired, because the drag can only start from within the QTableView (it only supports internal moves).

Comment: Anyway, how can I sublcass QTableView if the form is completely created via the Qt Designer?

Comment: Ah... I'm out of my depths here. I have no idea of subclassing using QtDesigner. Call me old fashioned, but I prefer typing everything by myself than use designer.

Comment: Also, *I think*, irrespective of where the origin of the drag is, the event will be fired as soon as the drag starts. For example, you start dragging "cell A". Moment you hold down "cell A" and move it the minimum distance required for the event to be considered drag, the `dragEnterEvent(..)` will be fired. I know this, as I have tested it in the [software](https://github.com/marcusbritanicus/NewBreeze/) I am developing.

Comment: I'm not done. What should I do inside `dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent*)`?  To me the standard action of Qt seems sufficient: the rows are dragged. Only, the model never reflects this.